# Fastest way to decode a sequence of integers

Tags: java, io, memory-mapped-files

Assume the following file format:

```
Integer1 Integer2 Integer3 Integer4 ...
```

These are binary integers written using DataInputStream. There are 22 billions of them written to a file with size about 90G.

The available RAM is > 2 * the size of the file.

So, it can fit in memory easily. What would be the fastest approach to read and decode such integers. Currently,

```
MappedByteBuffer reads 500M numbers in time: 212.986 seconds
DataInputStream wrapped around a BufferedInputStream reads 500M numbers in time 306.755 seconds.
```

Comment: Java's `Integer`s are 4 bytes (plus overhead if wrapped...), * 22 Billion ~> 81GB.  What kind of system are you talking about, that you think this could be fit into RAM?  Obviously, you're attempting to use a buffer, which should help.  What's the _goal_ here - what task are you trying to accomplish?  Given your current rate, expect processing to take about 9 hours at best...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the exact combination of JVM, OS, hardware and access patterns. Martin Thompson has written a program you can use to test  sequential I/O performance of various ways to read and write: http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-sequential-io-performance.html

Conclusion of his test on his platform: use RandomAccessFile.